# Thumbnail does not display in my Quarto blog

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, pandoc, quarto

I am building a Quarto Blog, in my post I am adding a image to, it shows in my post but at the homepage it gives a error as a thumbnail:

[image]

I tried in different ways to insert the image, all of them gave the same result:

- Using the visual mode in RStudio
- Using `image: "An intro to chi-squared test.png` in the `.qmd` header
- Using `![](images/An%20intro%20to%20chi-squared%20test.png)` inside my `.qmd`

After rendering each one, the image shows inside the post but does not as a thumbnail in my home, as shown in the figure above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! so I removed the image from inside the post but kept the image command in the post `.qmd` header.

```
image: "An intro to chi-squared test.png
```

Then in my main `index.qmd` file I added the following below listing:

```
  fields: [image, date, title, description, categories,author]
```

So my header became:

```
---
title: "Blog"
about:
  template: jolla
  image-width: 70%
listing:
  contents: posts
  fields: [image, date, title, description, categories,author]
  sort: "date desc"
  type: default
  categories: true
  sort-ui: false
  filter-ui: false
page-layout: full
title-block-banner: true
---
```

Now my blog looks like this:

[image]